# How do I change the colors in Highcharts zones?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I have this piece of code:

```
var rawData = [20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
    data = [
        [0, 100]
    ],
    overData = [
        [0, 0]
    ],
    underData = [
        [0, 0]
    ],
    zones = [],
    len = rawData.length,
    colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
    maxColor = colors.length,
    i,
    val,
    sum = 0,
    pos = 0,
    plotLines = [];
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        sum += rawData[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        pos += rawData[i];
        val = (sum - pos) / sum * 100;
        data.push([pos, val]);
        overData.push([pos, (100 - val) / 2]);
        underData.push([pos, (100 - val) / 2]);
        zones.push({
            value: pos,
            color: colors[i % maxColor]
        });

    plotLines.push({
        zIndex: 7,
        width: 3,
        color: '#aaa',
        value: pos,
        label: {
            text: rawData[i],
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            rotation: 0,
            y: -10,
            align: 'right',
            x: -12,
            style: {
                color: colors[i % maxColor],
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now this line seems to use the API to generate standard highcharts colors:

```
colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors
```

How can I set a color I define for each "zone"?  Could you please show me a small sample of how I could achieve a color for each zone?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean this: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/color-zones-simple ?

Comment: is it perhaps possible to create a JSFiddle?

Comment: You color is set here: `color: colors[i % maxColor]`. And `colors` array is defined here: `colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors`. Instead set `colors = ['#ff00ff', '#ffff00' ... ]`.